# problem in taking input after making a linkedlist input function

Tags: c++, linked-list

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class node {
 public:
  int data;
  node* next;
  node(int d) {
    data = d;
    next = NULL;
  }
};
void insertAtTail(node*& head, int d) {
  node* temp = head;
  node* n = new node(d);
  n->next = NULL;
  if (head == NULL) {
    head = n;
  } else {
    while (temp->next != NULL) {
      temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp->next = n;
  }
}
void buildList(node*& head, int t) {
  int data;
  cin >> data;
  int q = 1;
  while (q != t + 1) {
    insertAtTail(head, data);
    cin >> data;
    q++;
  }
  return;
}
int main() {
  node* head = NULL;
  int t, q;
  cin >> t;
  buildList(head, t);
  int u;
  cin >> u;
  cout << u << endl;
  print(head);
}
```

After making an input function for the Linked List (buildList) , whenever I declare another variable (int u) and take input, it always takes a garbage value and does not take the inputted value. Please review it and tell me where am I wrong

Comment: Please [edit] your question to tell us the actual input you have, and also show the expected and actual output of your program.

Comment: [`u` taked inputted value after commented out undefined `print(head);`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/u4ACQl3aTFPpbdBU).